# AirPort Extreme/Express 802.1X authentication and guest access

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, airport, osx-server

I've got a number of AirPort Expresses & Extremes set up to have main Wi-Fi and guest access. They work well but the problem is, people keep sharing the password for the main network and I'd like to put 802.1X authentication or RADIUS on the main network. The issue is, I'm not sure if activating RADIUS or 802.1X authentication only applies to the main network or the guest as well (which is not ideal).

Ideally my setup would be as follows:

**Main Network**

802.1X certificate based authentication (preferred) so that only approved devices can connect to the main network.

**Guest Network**

WPA2 Encryption (password only) for guests- no certificate needed.

I've got an OS X Server set up to distribute configuration profiles to known devices so distributing the certificate shouldn't be that much of a headache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

802.1X only applies to the main network an Apple base stations.

Also, on the Apple base stations, 802.1X requires RADIUS. They are not independent.

Comment: Good stuff, this looks like it's going to do exactly what I was hoping for.